# Boolean Solver Issue

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to Blender and getting to grips with everything.

I've tried to make a simple difference boolean but the modifier only works on "Fast" Solver and not "Exact". Is there a reason for this?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello ! The exact solver sometimes fails when the mesh is not manifold. Make sure both meshes are manifold, and merge vertices that are located at the same place with Merge > By distance in edit mode

Comment: Would you mind giving more information on this? To me this looks like to cuboids, the one you subtract is set to display as wire only. If I recreate this, it works in _Fast_ and _Exact_ mode. Any more there is to know about them? Are they the exact same width for example?